# Cannot read property 'userService' of undefined - implementing async validator (Angular 12)

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I've been trying to implement async validation for last few days. But none of the tutorials/solutions are working!

**Service code-**

```
getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(userId:any):Observable<any>{
    const url = ``; //url goes here
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }
```

**Component code-**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      userId: ['', [Validators.required],[this.validate]]})
}
validate(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    console.log(control.value);
    return of(control.value)
      .pipe(
        delay(10),
        switchMap((value) =>
          this.userService.getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(value).pipe(map(x => {
            return x.exists ? { exists: true } : null;
          }))
        )
      );
  }
```

**Html code-**

```html
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="1 1 calc(25% - 10px)" fxFlex.lt-md="1 1 calc(25% - 10px)"
                    fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="from-color" *ngIf="!data">
          <mat-label class="label-padding">User ID</mat-label>
             <input class="label-padding" formControlName="userId" matInput placeholder="User ID" required />
                <div style="color: red; font-weight: bold;" *ngIf="userId.errors?.exists">Already
                      Exists !</div>
     </mat-form-field>
```

In the console-
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvWaA.png)

In the console, while I write something in the input, with **every key storke** it prints the value, but after that tells that **value is undefined**!

What is the **reason** behind this error? And how can I **solve** this? It should work properly so that the **async validator** works fine as well.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: It may be that `this` is not referring to the component - inside the `scope` of the `return of`. Can you check it debugging it?

Comment: In the **return of(control.value)** the value is what I have entered. While I enter 'a', it shows 'a'. But after continuing it ends up showing error.

Comment: See the answer below, as I said `this` wasn't in the scope you tought. That's why the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's more simple than all this:

```
validate = (
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return this.userService.getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(control.value).pipe(
          map(x => {
            return x? { exists: true } : null;
          })
      
    );
```

(*)I suppose that your service return null if there're no duplicate

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdscqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts) (to check, "fool" is repeat)

If you're using material

```
  <mat-form-field class="name" appearance="outline">
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="userId">
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('userId')?.hasError('required')">
      Name is required*
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('userId')?.hasError('exists')">
      Name repeat
    </mat-error>
    <mat-hint *ngIf="form.get('userId')?.pending">Validating...</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

But it's good that check errors 'onblur' (else the error is not showed by defect: in material, if we not use a custom error matcher, the error only is showed if the formControl is touched (edit and blur)

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  userId: ['', [Validators.required], [this.validate]]
},{updateOn:'blur'});
```

Comment: it shows "Name repeat" message always even if it does not exist in the database. That is the problem, I've tried & followed almost all the tutorials & blogs; but those have not helped me with this ASYNC VALIDATION yet.

Comment: @Valkyrie_30, what return your service if a user exist? waht return if not exist?

Comment: Its return type is bool, returns false if doesn't exist & true if exists

Comment: then use the map like mine: `pipe(map(x => {return x? { exists: true } : null;})`, you can see if work using "tap" `pipe(tap(x=>{console.log("response:",x)}),map(x => {return x? { exists: true } : null;})`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq6eM.png
First response is when entered data exists in Database. Second one for when input data does not exist in database. **But**, shows "Name repeat" in both cases! (I've used the 'tap')

Comment: `pipe(map((x:any)=>{ return x.apiData?{exist:true}:null})`. See that you check "x.apiData". If only check "x", as x is an object the condition (x) is fulfilled always

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to reproduce the error in the below [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mffghf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

The problem is that  `this` in this context does not refer to the class

A simple solution is to simply use arrow function for validate

```
validate = (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    console.log(control.value);
    return of(control.value)
      .pipe(
        delay(10),
        switchMap((value) =>
          this.userService.getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(value).pipe(map(x => {
            return x.exists ? { exists: true } : null;
          }))
        )
      );
  }
```

See this **[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czrmqa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**